# Visual Basic Ftp Information Security

Tags: vba, security, ftp

I am working on a project. And in this project i must connect with my ftp account. But when i run the project with a hex editor all the passwords show up. I even obfuscate it. They can deobfuscate it. So what must i do?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Storing passwords in code is never a good idea. I would recommend you use a hashed password, stored in file and load it if needed. As additional common inforamtion about the topic you may find the following link useful: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm